# Nhibernate 2: CreateQuery not supporting chinese character

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Following is my code:

```
String hsql = "from Customer c where c.name='测试' ";
IQuery query = _session.CreateQuery(hsql);
query.List();
```

when executing, no exception thrown, but no query result return (they should return based the condition `c.name='测试'`)

this is the sql NHibernate generate for the hsql:

```
select customer0_.CUSTOMER_NO as CUSTOMER1_, customer0_.CODE as CODE9_, customer0_.NAME as NAME9_, customer0_.STATUS as STATUS9_, customer0_.LAST_OPE RATOR_NO as LAST5_9_
from CUSTOMER customer0_ where (customer0_.NAME='????')
```

The chinese characters '测试' in hsql become '????' in sql.

The chinese characters are saving successfully when I am adding a customer through Nhibernate. Here the issue is only when I am searching a text using CreateQuery. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it using a parameter?

```
String hsql = "from Customer c where c.name=:name";
IQuery query = _session.CreateQuery(hsql).SetString("name", "测试");
query.List();
```

related
[Unicode String in Hibernate Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/447566/40822)

Comment: Have you tried with QueryOver? It's odd because I'd think the HQL parameter would be identical to parameters used for saving the data.

Comment: I am using Nhibernate 2.1 and do not have QueryOver I think.

Comment: only thing I can think of is for some reason it's not using an `nvarchar` parameter...