# NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException in Orchard CMS

Tags: nhibernate, unicode, orchardcms

Using Orchard.Projections module, it's not possible to search in Unicode text. For example the result query is `Select ... From ... Where ... Col Like '%term%'` but we expected `Select ... From ... Where ... Col Like N'%term%'` (`N` included after `Like`). Looking it up in code we find `public static BinaryExpression Like()` in *Orchard.ContentManagement.HqlRestrictions*. By adding N and changing `value = "'%" + FormatValue(value, false) + "%'";` into `value = "N'%" + FormatValue(value, false) + "%'";` we get this error:

```
NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException was caught
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTokenException' was thrown. near line 9, column 61
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\ErrorCounter.cs:line 73
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\QueryTranslatorImpl.cs:line 479
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryString, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Hql\Ast\ANTLR\ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.cs:line 19
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLStringQueryPlan.cs:line 24
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLStringQueryPlan.cs:line 16
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLStringQueryPlan..ctor(String hql, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\HQLStringQueryPlan.cs:line 14
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(String queryString, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Engine\Query\QueryPlanCache.cs:line 62
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(String query, Boolean shallow) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:line 310
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\AbstractSessionImpl.cs:line 289
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.DefaultHqlQuery.Slice(Int32 skip, Int32 count) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\DefaultHqlQuery.cs:line 188
       at Orchard.Projections.Services.ProjectionManager.GetContentItems(Int32 queryId, Int32 skip, Int32 count)
       at Orchard.Projections.Drivers.ProjectionPartDriver.<>c__DisplayClass2e.<Display>b__1e(Object shape)
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass12.<ContentShape>b__11(BuildShapeContext ctx) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 135
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentPartDriver`1.<>c__DisplayClass15.<ContentShapeImplementation>b__14(BuildShapeContext ctx) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentPartDriver.cs:line 140
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.ApplyImplementation(BuildShapeContext context, String displayType) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 45
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.ContentShapeResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\ContentShapeResult.cs:line 21
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.CombinedResult.Apply(BuildDisplayContext context) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\CombinedResult.cs:line 28
       at Orchard.ContentManagement.Drivers.Coordinators.ContentPartDriverCoordinator.<>c__DisplayClassa.<BuildDisplay>b__9(IContentPartDriver driver) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Drivers\Coordinators\ContentPartDriverCoordinator.cs:line 49
       at Orchard.InvokeExtensions.Invoke[TEvents](IEnumerable`1 events, Action`1 dispatch, ILogger logger) in d:\Projects\...\src\Orchard\InvokeExtensions.cs:line 17
  InnerException:
```

*line 9, column 61* indicates the position of 'N'.

Any idea?
How can we use this module to search in unicode text without changing database collation?

Orchard version is 1.8.1

Comment: *Just... out of the world of your **wrapper** over native NHibernate...* Native HQL in NHibernate does support params `var hql="FROM Entity e WHERE e.Property Like :value";` and by setting the value with unicode method: `.SetString("value", unicodeValue);` - generated SQL works exactly as expected...

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy, I've posted a discussion, https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/578488. Is it possible to move the thread into issues? By the way, any quick solution? We might not be able to wait for next release. Thanks

Comment: Maybe it solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447566/unicode-string-in-hibernate-queries

Comment: CTRL+A, CTRL+C, CTRL+V ;) A workaround I can see if you can't fix it yourself or wait for a fix is to switch from projections to straight HQL queries. I have a series of posts that should get you started: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Tags/NHibernate

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix. I've changed collation setting directly of database